# Room Persistence Library: attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Everything was working fine when I was using 1.0.0-alpha5 version of Room Persistence Library. But, after updating to 1.0.0-alpha9 version, I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/package_name/databases/app_db

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

I am using MVP architecture with dagger 2. I have got DatabaseHelper class which initializes RoomDatabase:

```
@Singleton
public class DatabaseHelper {

private final AppDatabase appDatabase;

@Inject
public DatabaseHelper(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "app_db").build();        
}

public List<DifficultyEntity> getAllDifficulties() {
        return appDatabase.difficultyDao().getAllDifficulties();
}
```

My RoomDatabase:

```
@Database(version = 22, entities = {
        DifficultyEntity.class, // ....
})
@Singleton
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract DifficultyDao difficultyDao();
    //....
}
```

When I call `getAllDifficulties` method, I am getting that error.

Here's logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/package_name/databases/app_db
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1783)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1729)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:241)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.createMasterTableIfNotExists(RoomOpenHelper.java:130)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:106)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:99)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$1.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:64)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:82)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:191)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.daos.RecordingDao_Impl.getAllRecordings(RecordingDao_Impl.java:167)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.DatabaseHelper.getAllRecording(DatabaseHelper.java:361)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:77)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:74)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT 2:**

After some time, I started getting different error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:118)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:99)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$1.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:64)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:82)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:191)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.daos.RecordingDao_Impl.getAllRecordings(RecordingDao_Impl.java:167)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.DatabaseHelper.getAllRecording(DatabaseHelper.java:361)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:77)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:74)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And when I updated the version number, I am getting Migration error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 22 to 23 is necessary. Please provide a Migration in the builder or call fallbackToDestructiveMigration in the builder in which case Room will re-create all of the tables.
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:81)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$1.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:49)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:82)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:191)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.daos.RecordingDao_Impl.getAllRecordings(RecordingDao_Impl.java:167)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.data.local.database.DatabaseHelper.getAllRecording(DatabaseHelper.java:361)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:77)
       at uz.iumarov.ieltsspeaking.ui.main.recordingsFragment.RecordingsPresenter$1.call(RecordingsPresenter.java:74)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please, somebody help me!

**SOLVED**

I deleted my app and reinstalled. Now, everything is working fine with alpha9 verison.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the entire Java stack trace plus your code that is triggering the stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @CommonsWare I solved it. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: I know this a bit late but someone still having the same issue can refer this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/285#issuecomment-448850055

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to provide Migration.In Live App you can't tell every person please  delete app and reinstall app.

In Room New Version  1.0.0-alpha9 Room adds support for the NOT NULL constraint.

That is going to change the schema that Room generates. Because it changes the schema, it also changes the identityHash of the DB and that is used by Room to uniquely identify every DB version. Therefore, we need a migration

For Migration From  1.0.0-alpha5 to  1.0.0-alpha9  please visit below article. Very Good Article for Migrate from old version to  1.0.0-alpha9 version.

https://medium.com/@manuelvicnt/android-room-upgrading-alpha-versions-needs-a-migration-with-kotlin-or-nonnull-7a2d140f05b9

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue.
Be aware that database may persist after uninstall.

In manifest you need to do

```
    android:allowBackup="false"
```